# mongodb fetch records if array exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections:

**Vehicles:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "a1",
        "type:": "car",
        "make": "Honda",
        "specifications": ["1", "2"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "a2",
        "type:": "car",
        "make": "Toyota",
        "specifications": ["3", "4"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "a3",
        "type:": "car",
        "make": "Honda",
        "specifications": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "a4",
        "type:": "car",
        "make": "Toyota"
    }
]
```

**Specifications:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "color": "Black"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "sunroof": "yes"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "engine": "1800 CC"
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "bodyType": "Sedan"
    }
]
```

I want to fetch those records which has at least one specification.
And also the details from specifications collections should appear in Vehicles collections somewhere.

**Expected response:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "a1",
        "make": "Honda",
        "type:": "car",
        "carSpecifications": [
            {
                "color": "Black"
            },
            {
                "sunroof": "yes"
            }
        ],

    },
    {
        "_id": "a2",
        "make": "Toyota",
        "type:": "car",
        "specifications": [
            {
                "engine": "1800 CC"
            },
            {
                "bodyType": "Sedan"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now what I tried so far is:

```
db.vehicles.find({type: "car", "specifications": {$exists: true}}, {fields: {"specifications.$": 1}}).fetch()
```

this query is returning all the records from Vehicles.

After getting all the records I put a loop on the records I get and check manually `if specifications.length > 0` than I query from Specifications collection accordingly.

Can I achieve all this with a single query?

Comment: The type field in the `cars` collection was named as `type: ", is it a typo?

Comment: @YongShun no it isnt a typo. its an attribute, but just an example value

Comment: @YongShun I just updated my question a  bit, have a look now

Answer (score 1):

You should look for an aggregation query.

1. `$match` - Filter documents with `"type:" "car"` and `specifications` is not an empty array (with `$ifNull`, default as `[]` when `specifications` field is `null` or not existed).
2. `$lookup` - Vehicles collection join specifications collection (Refer to [Use $lookup with an Array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array)). Work with `pipeline` to return the array without the `_id` field (Refer to [Correlated Subqueries Using Concise Syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax)).

> MongoDB v5 query

```
db.vehicles.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        "type:": "car"
      },
      {
        $expr: {
          $ne: [
            {
              $ifNull: [
                "$specifications",
                []
              ]
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "specifications",
    localField: "specifications",
    foreignField: "_id",
    pipeline: [
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "specifications"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (v5)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HWBqsQ_H3MP)

---

> MongoDB v4 query

```
db.vehicles.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        "type:": "car"
      },
      {
        $expr: {
          $ne: [
            {
              $ifNull: [
                "$specifications",
                []
              ]
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "specifications",
    let: {
      specifications: "$specifications"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $in: [
              "$_id",
              "$$specifications"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "specifications"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (v4)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2OZPcK9Hrlj)

Comment: Isn't there any shorter or optimized way to query this? for me it seems like we could shorten the check for specifications to something like specifications.length > 0

Comment: No, MongoDB doesn't support such `specifications.length > 0`, this is JS syntax. Or probably work with `$size` to get array length and use `$gt` operator. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sIcTGvP-i_D)

Comment: I am getting this error when I run your example according to my schema: MongoError: $lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you used? I think you are not able to use 'localField' or 'foreignField' with pipeline if your MongoDB version is lower than v5.

Comment: I am using MongoDB server version: 4.2.5